# Gstreamer G711 rate decrease to 8000

Tags: gstreamer

How can I decrease g.711 (PCMA) sound rate from 16000 to 8000?
I use this pipeline:

```
gst-launch autoaudiosrc ! queue ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=3001
```

And, as i told, rate is 16kHz, but i need 8kHz. After i've been tryied such pipeline:

```
gst-launch alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1,depth=16,width=16,rate=8000 ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=3001
```

But still 16kHz. Then i've been tryied:

```
gst-launch alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1,depth=8,width=8,rate=8000 ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=3001
```

But got an error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link audioconvert0 to alawenc0
```

Answer (score 1):

alawenc element doesn't accept 8 bit samples, it can only handle 16 bits as in your second pipeline. Why it is still 16kHZ? It should be 8kHZ.

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc num-buffers=100 ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,rate=8000 ! alawenc ! qtmux ! filesink location=/tmp/alawtest.mov
```

This pipeline (from gstreamer 1.0) creates a 8 kHz alaw sample

Please note that you are using gstreamer 0.10 that is unmaintained and obsolete for years.

Comment: Thanks, **thiagoss**. Your example should work. But my problem was in my device, that I was trying to use. The device doesn't support 8kHz frequency of audio, only 16kHz.

Comment: Try adding an audioresample and audiorate after alsasrc to make sure it will be converting to your requested format if it can't capture directly

Comment: I already tried many variants, including your, but it didn't help me, but thank you for your trying to help me.

Comment: Can you post the exact error and the pipeline with audioresample, audiorate and audioconvert that you used?

Comment: I've been asked the same question on the gstreamer's forum a few weeks ago (http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/G-711-decrease-to-8kHz-td4669957.html), but i concluded that i have problem with my device's codecs.